# UIScrollView bounces when content is smaller than view's size

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

How can I simply let the scrollview bounce, when the content size is smaller than the view's frame and when I drag it?

like iPhone's app search results.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

see [UIScrollView (paging mode) bounces only when there two or more pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716342/uiscrollview-paging-mode-bounces-only-when-there-two-or-more-pages)

you'd better set the property:

```
scroll.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
scroll.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
```

Answer (score 4):

answer myself: the simplest way would be to set the height of the content size to be the height of the frame plus 1. kind of stupid but according to document it only scrolls when size is bigger than frame.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer `.xib` just check `Bounce Vertically`.

[image]

Comment: thanks but it's a 7 years old question and back then Xcode looked way different...